# WPF ContextMenu get parent MenuItem Tag from Child MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and its whole binding model, and I have been tasked to include a context menu that has the following structure:

-Add Row Below

--List item 1

--List item 2

-Add Row Above

--List item 1

--List item 2

I have the following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <c:ArrayList x:Key="SubMenu" x:Shared="false">
        <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding Tag}" Command="Item1Command"  Header="Item1" />
        <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding Tag}" Command="Item2Command" Header="Item2"/>
    </c:ArrayList>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid.ContextMenu >
    <ContextMenu Opened="MenuItem_Click" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
        <MenuItem Header="Above" Tag="{Binding Path=AboveCommand}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SubMenu}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Below" Tag="{Binding BelowCommand}"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource SubMenu}" >  />
    </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

I basically want to learn how I get pass the Parent Menu item Tag to the child CommandParameter, so that I know if I am adding an item above or below. I would like to be able to do this all through XAML and not in code behind if possible!

Comment: Use FindAncestor to find parent and send it as parameter in ContextMenu.

Comment: I have tried the following many times in the SubMenu Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=Tag}". And it never seems to find the parent